# Правильная архитектура кода на примере класса User | Php

Tags: php, ооп, классы, архитектура, методы

На стадии изучения ООП. Заметил у себя привычку делать почти все методы в классах статическими. На примере класса User:

```
class User
{
  public static function auth(){/*Авторизация*/}
  public static function register(){/*Регистрация*/}
  public static function getUser(){/*Получение массива данных пользователя*/}
  public static function exitUser(){/*Деавторизация*/}
  public static function editAvatar(){/*Смена аватара*/}
  public static function editPassword(){/*Смена пароля*/}
}
```

Причин на это несколько:

1. Я переписываю процедурный код, там получаемые данные идут в виде массива. Метод getUser в данный момент как раз и возвращает данные о пользователе в виде массива.
2. Попросту нет причин создавать объект класса User только ради того, чтобы передать данные в условный метод register, который добавит запись в БД и поставит cookies.

И у меня опасение, что позже это может плохо обернуться. Возможно я нарушаю 1 из принципов ООП - инкапсуляцию. Я так понимаю, лучше все же делать получение данных о пользователе в виде объекта через метод __construct, а остальные методы оставить статическими? В общем нужны советы по правильной архитектуре кода.

Comment: Если нет причин создавать объект - то зачем вообще создавать класс? Чтобы похвастаться что умеешь в ООП? Ну так нет, не умеешь.

Comment: как умеешь на данны момент, так и прогь, мало практики, раз у тебя все в статике))

Comment: несколько странно иметь `User::getUser`

Comment: @u_mulder, а я сказал, что умею? Я в самом начале написал, что на стадии изучения ООП и попросил совета по правильной архитектуре, а не доводов умею я в ООП или нет.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, верно, практики мало, цель как раз и в изучении ООП, а не просто написать любым способом)

Comment: @teran, в итоге переписал этот метод в конструктор, где уже проверка авторизован пользователь или нет. Методы редактирования пользователя - не статические. Методы авторизации и регистрации оставил статическими (оно и логично).